# Check if caret is visible on Screen View

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I've been thinking all this while how to check if caret is visible on the present Screen view of a Richtextbox.
The issue is that the caret may be at the end of the richtextbox and the scroll is at the beginning of the box, how can I programmatically know if the caret is visible on the present screen view or not.
NB. the caret may not necessarily be at the bottom.

Comment: You forgot to mention the UI Platform (e.g., WinForms, WPF). Tag your question accordingly. A description of the reason why you need this information may also be useful, since there's always the chance that there's a different, possibly simpler, solution to the whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation for the `RichTextBox` control to see what members it has and whether any of them are applicable? You shouldn't be posting any question here that can be answered just by reading the documentation for the type or member you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is WinForms

One thing that I think you could use is `RichTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex()`, and `RichTextBox1.SelectionStart`:

```
' Y pos of caret
Dim CaretYPos As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart).Y
Dim CharHeight As Integer = 4 ' Height of each line

If CaretYPos >= RichTextBox1.Height - CharHeight Then
    ' Caret is hidden below screen view
ElseIf CaretYPos < -CharHeight Then
    ' Caret is hidden above screen view
Else
    ' Caret is visible
End If
```

Though you might have to account for higher dpi displays when it comes to the `CharHeight`

Comment: You just need `if not richTextBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(richTextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox.SelectionStart))) then ' Outside visible bounds end if`. BTW, the Height of a Line is not 4 pixels (and you cannot assume it is).

Comment: @Jimi Ahh yeah that's way more elegant, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: There is an extra ")" in your answer... correct is "))" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted @jimi 's comment to my C# application and it worked fine in conjunction with the `ScrollToCaret()` method. Thanks.

```
private void CheckAndMakeSelectionVisible()
{
    // other stuff
    if(!IsCaretVisible()) {
        richTextMsg.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
private bool IsCaretVisible()
{
    if (!richTextMsg.ClientRectangle.Contains(richTextMsg.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextMsg.SelectionStart)))
    {
        // Outside visible bounds 
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```